# The war with Grindelwald links with Muggle WW2. Was there a Muggle war that links with the war with Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, jk-rowling

[It has been established](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47835/32390) that the war with Grindelwald was hand-in-hand with the Muggle World War Two, with Grindelwald being defeated in 1945.

According to [@Au101](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/46027/au101), Voldemort was defeated in the summer of 1998.

Was there a Muggle war that the wizard war against the most powerful dark wizard **ever** linked with?

Comment: I think it might be better to rephrase the question to *was* there a war that links to the war(s) with Voldemort rather than assuming there necessarily was

Comment: Why do you think there is a link?

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - see TheDoc's comment above. I assumed that there was a link because I thought that if Grindelwald caused (or helped cause) a major war all over the world, a much more powerful wizard like Voldemort must have caused a much more major war.

Comment: P.S. There's more than one question here, but Voldemort was finally defeated in the summer of 1998

Comment: Out of universe, of course, JKR had the freedom to select the schedule of Grindelweld's war to match with real-world history, but didn't have as much flexibility when it came to Voldemort.

Comment: Lol, Voldy failed taking over a school, what big implications could that have for the muggles? [Yes I know the Deatheaters caused some broken bridges, storm etc in major cities, but thats it]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No wars on a global scale are linked with the rise of Voldemort, neither his first time or his return.**

Tom Riddle returns to the wizarding world in 1970 and goes by the name of Voldemort. He gathers power and wreaks havoc until his attempted murder of Harry Potter in 1981. In 1991 the Harry Potter books begin and Voldemort starts his path back to existence, until the end of the Harry Potter books in 1998.

There are many wars that are going on in various parts of the world, but all are mostly local and only have minimal involvement from outside parties.The UK was actively participating in the [Sarawak Communist Insurgency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarawak_Communist_Insurgency), the [Dhofar Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhofar_Rebellion) and [The Troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Troubles) during the 70’s, but all of those started before the rise of Voldemort.

A few wars involving the UK did occur in the 90’s, but all were localized civil wars: The [Sierra Leone Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Leone_Civil_War), the [Nepalese Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepalese_Civil_War) and the [Afghan Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_war_in_Afghanistan_(1996%E2%80%932001)) .

Answer (score 6):

**Not really** - though you could make the argument for his rise and fall running parallel to the major 'threats' to the West.

- Voldemort first rises to power in the middle of the Vietnam War; pretty much indisputably the USSR's most successful proxy-war against the U.S.
- he suffers his first defeat in the middle of the Soviet war in Afghanistan; America's great proxy-war success(despite events in 2001) that helped crush the USSR's economy and was one of the largest contributing factors to its fall.
- at the start of the books, both organizations have utterly collapsed. While in general seen as a peaceful era; there are many small hotspots such as Mogadishu, Desert Storm, Bosnia etc. The giant threat of Communism/a dark wizards army are gone, to be replaced by non-state actors, small scale conflict and the more subtle instability that is more in-line with Voldemort's actions in the books- an infiltrator hiding within the ministry rather than an attacker from outside of it.