# Did WW2 happen in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter

So, there's odds and ends of 'their world is our world' about Harry Potter. Quite a lot about the series suggest that wizards are in our world, in secret. Of course, non-magical folks wouldn't notice anything, right? Because they're a secret...

So here's the thing, great seismic events in history would have happened the same way, presumably. So did, for instance, the second world war happen in the world of Harry Potter.

And if so, *why didn't the wizards do anything about it?*

Comment: “The trouble is, the other side can do magic too, Prime Minister.”

Comment: Someone already asked this.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47835/what-is-the-connection-between-grindelwald-and-world-war-ii

Comment: The real question here is why magical society didn't do anything about WW2, which is answered by the answers to the question of why *Dumbledore* didn't do anything about it.

Comment: But why limit it to WW2? Why didn't wizards do anything about the Syrian civil war? The Rwandan genocide? The Greek ethnic cleansing? The Falklands war, the war of 1812, the cancellation of *Firefly*?

Comment: @Bishop Are you telling me Hitler was a dark wizard?

Comment: @Adamant A series of questions, then?

Comment: I don’t think that would be the best idea, unfortunately. Though a more general question *might* not be a duplicate.

Comment: @AJFaraday - I guess maybe Hitler was *working with* or under the control of a Dark Wizard? Stay tuned for *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* episode V (2021).

Comment: @Adamant about your question i think the wizard world have more trouble to deal with, they mustn't get involved with something they don't have anything to do, and if they stop all these wards. then what? the whole world (Muggle world) will start to throwing fingered to wizard world about everything happening.

Comment: lets see about the wizard in all civilizations, if you're a wizard you must got killed, and i think if there's a wars happened between the two worlds, the wizards Obliviate it from Muggle's mind.